# Is it possible to execute deployment of AWS CDK asynchronously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

The command `cdk deploy ...` is used to deploy one or more CloudFormation stacks.  When it executes, it displays messages resulting from the deployment of the various stacks and this can take some time.

The [`deploy` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tools.html) supports the `--notification-arns` parameter, which is an array of ARNs of SNS topics that CloudFormation will notify with stack related events.

Is it possible to execute `cdk deploy` and not have it report to the console its progress (i.e. the command exits immediately after uploading the new CloudFormation assets) and simply rely on the SNS topic as a means of getting feedback on the progress of a deployment?

Comment: To my knowledge its not possible to put that into background in a proper way. But you dont need to use --notification-arns to get updates about the stack creation. You can just login into AWS console and check the "cloudformation" service. There you have all the same infos you get on the console, plus some more. Furthermore CDK asks you for aproval in the console if not disabled via --require-approval never. Even if you put it into background by appending "&" at the end of the command (linux or mac), sysout is printed to console.

Comment: Thanks, but any interaction with the console means automation is not possible. The whole point of using notifications via SNS/SQS is to avoid a user needing to log in to the console and to allow for automated monitoring of the progress of a Cfn deployment.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way (untested) would be to use `nohup`

```sh
$ nohup cdk ... --require-approval never 1>/dev/null
```

The `--require-approval never` simply means it wont stop to ask for permission for `sercurity` requests and obviously `nohup` allows the command to run with out terminating.

Its the only solution I can think of that is quick.

Another solution for long term would be to use the `CdkToolkit` to create your own script for deployment. Take a look at [cdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts) command to get an idea. This is been something Ive wanted from `aws-cdk` for a while - I want custom deploy scripts rather than using the shell.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really execute the changesets asynchronously, it merely means it runs in the background when run through bash. Background is that I want to launch the CDK deploy through a lambda and have the lambda exit immediately after starting the deploy and rely on notifications through SQS/SNS to monitor the progress of the deployment .  Thanks for the `CdkToolkit` idea, I'll take a look there.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to asynchronously deploy a cdk app via the `--no-execute` flag:

```
cdk deploy StackX --no-execute
change_set_name = aws cloudformation list-change-sets --stack-name StackX --query "Summaries[0].ChangeSetId" --output text
aws cloudformation execute-change-set --change-set-name $change_set_name
```

For my case this works, because I use this method to deploy new stacks only, so there will ever be only exactly 1 change set for this stack and I can retrieve it with the query for the entry with index 0. If you wish to update existing stacks, you will have to select the correct change set from the list returned by the list-change-sets command.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - I didn't want to keep a console open while waiting for a long-running init script on an ec2 instance to finish. I've hit Ctrl-C after publishing was completed and the changeset got created. It kept running and I've checked the status in the Cloudformation view. Not perfect and not automation-friendly, but I didn't need to keep the process running on my machine.